# Entity Framework turn off caching

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am trying to figure out how to turn off caching of the DbContext using the repository pattern.  Right now my view and CRUD functions use the same context, so putting .AsNoTracking() on the DbSet is not working because updating the data is not happening as it did before.

```
_context.Entry(e).State = e.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Can someone explain caching in EntityFramework, so that I can provide dynamic functionality where if a user updates a record and then they click a link to view other data, then the data represented on the new grid takes in to effect the change from the previous controller action...hope that makes since.

View Orders -> Update Order -> Save Order -> View Users -> View correctly shows Item count aggregate based off of order changes.

Comment: Start with using a new context instance for every user action. It will ensure that you will get fresh data every time. It will also ensure that your application will work.

Comment: @Ladislav, I am using Ninject to attach a new repository to the controller when created.  I would assume that the context is new everytime because in the repository there is a private variable that will create a new context.  As a side question can I assume that Ninject will DI a brand new repository on each request for the controller?

Comment: That depends on Ninject configuration. The "caching" in EF exists only within same context instance.

Comment: @Ladislav, `ninjectKernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();` and `ninjectKernel.Bind<IOrderRepository>().To<OrderRepository>();` are used with constructors that have `public class UserRepository { private DbContext db = new DbContext(); public IQueryable<User> Users { get { return db.Users.AsNoTracking(); } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question you are asking is not really easy.
what you would do depends on what type of entities you are using
as you probably know there are several generic options - EF entities, Self Tracking entities, POCO no proxy, POCO with proxy
depending on what you have you would either

1) reattach entity, call `Load` on navigation property of entity

2) reattach entity, call `LoadProperty` on context

3) just call either Load / LoadProperty if the context remain the same

What you refer as caching in fact is entity tracking , so you can turn it off either detaching entities or setting `MergeOption` to `MergeOption.NoTracking` on `ObjectQuery`